# Oxford 8 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

I  have the Oxford ed.8 setup folder on my hard disk in folder (Downloads) and here what I've got in the terminal when I try to install it (the install folder  has setup for Linux with name: linux):

```
WARNING:root:python-html2text is not present. HTML pages will not be converted into text.
shams@shams-MS-7592:~$ cd Downloads/Oxford/linux/
shams@shams-MS-7592:~/Downloads/Oxford/linux$ ./setup.sh
The setup program seems to have failed on amd64/unknown

Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because probably you're trying to install a 32-bit on a 64-bit system.
Try this-

```
linux32 ./setup.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps:

1. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and `cd` to the target directory containing the *setup.sh*:

   ```
   cd /to/target/directory
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   cd /media/OALD8
   ```
2. And execute the *setup.sh* file with (or `sudo ./setup.sh`):

   ```
   ./setup.sh
   ```

   *(running without `sudo` will create a local installation without root access.)*
3. Go through the licence agreement, on the prompt, hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to agree, specify the *installation path* or hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key to use the default, and finally hit <kbd>Y</kbd> on the *continue insatllation* prompt.
4. A desktop desktop shortcut will be created on your desktop. To make it executable, run this command in terminal:

   ```
   chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/oald8.desktop
   ```

   To make it available in the Dash's application lens:

   ```
   sudo cp $HOME/Desktop/oald8.desktop /usr/share/applications/
   ```

Double click the desktop icon or search *oald8* in Dash and click to launch the program:
[image: snap1]

---

#### PS. Resolving dependencies:

The error message that you've posted demands installation of `python-html2text` and you can do this with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-html2text
```

*(which is available under the universe section, so make sure you have allowed downloads from the repository. Here's a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) showing how you can do that; remember to update the package list with `apt-get` after adding the repository.)*

After installing `python-html2text` run the script again and it's not unexpected if you further encounter some more dependency problems, just get the packages installed and continue.

---

#### Alternatives:

- ***"Artha"***, *A handy off-line thesaurus based on WordNet*:

  *Section - Universe/utils*

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install artha
  ```

  [image: artha_snap]
- ***"GoldenDict"***, offering feature-rich dictionary lookup program using WebKit for an accurate articles' representation, complete with all formatting, colors, images and links.

  *Section - Universe/utils*

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install goldendict
  ```

  [image: goldendict_snap]
- ***Gnome Dictionary***:

  *Section - Universe/gnome*

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary
  ```

  [image: gnome-dictionary_snap]
- ***`dict`*** - a CLI client to `dictd` server (offline usage):

  *Section - text*

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dict
  sudo apt-get install dictd
  ```

  Installing English dictionary databeses (*gcide, wn, devil*):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dict-gcide
  sudo apt-get install dict-wn
  sudo apt-get install dict-devil
  ```

  Installing English Thesaurus database (*moby-thesaurus*):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dict-moby-thesaurus
  ```

  **Usage**:

  1. Using a particular database (*eg. WordNet - wn*):

     ```
     dict -d wn "dictionary"
     ```
  2. Not specifying a dict-database will output definitions/translations/thesaurus from all available databases. eg.

     ```
      dict "dictionary"
     ```

Comment: i got it (but without (/) in the first, i mean cd Downloads/Oxford/linux    but when i try ./setup.sh i get:
bash: ./setup.sh: Permission denied

Comment: ..you can check the permission and ownership of the script with `ls -l setup.sh`.. and if the script demands to be run as root (i.e. if the script attempts to copy/create files in locations owned by root) try running the script with `sudo ./setup.sh`

Comment: Ty for the help, still couldn't install it, i'v changed the permission in the setup.sh and here what i'v got when i ./setup.sh
(me)@(me)-MS-7592:~/Downloads/Oxford/linux$ ./setup.sh
The setup program seems to have failed on amd64/unknown

Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
(me)@me-MS-7592:~/Downloads/Oxford/linux$

Comment: ok I'v edited it.

Comment: The question is how to resolve the problem after doin `./setup.sh` inside linux directory, but the answer repeats the same procedure as asked in the question.